# Как правильно прописать задачу в .gitlab-ci.yml чтобы она выполнялась только при merge requests?

Tags: gitlab, непрерывная-интеграция, gitlab-ci

Как правильно прописать задачу в .gitlab-ci.yml чтобы она выполнялась только при merge requests?

```
test_c:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something. It will only run when all jobs in the"
    - echo "build stage are complete."
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

Вот эта джоба не выполняется при мерж реквесте. Но не выполняется и при коммитах в мастер или девелоп.

Answer (score 0):

А следующие условия выполняются?

To enable pipelines for merge requests:

- You must have maintainer permissions.
- Your repository must be a GitLab repository, not an external
  repository.
- In GitLab 11.10 and later, you must be using GitLab Runner 11.9.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/